# d3 pie chart text label wrap

Tags: html, css, d3.js, d3pie.js

I'm using [d3pie.js](http://d3pie.org/#about) to create a d3 pie chart. 
This is the configuration that I'm using.

```
 var pie = new d3pie("shpPie", {
        "size": {
            "canvasHeight": 350,
            "canvasWidth": 350,
            "pieOuterRadius": "50%",
            "pieInnerRadius": "50%"
        },
        "data": {
            "sortOrder": "value-asc",
            "content": [
                  {"label":"Total Foreign","value":3.55},
                  {"label":"Total Institutions","value":0.89},
                  {"label":"Total Govt Holding","value":0},
                  {"label":"Total Non Promoter Corporate Holding","value":0.20},
                  {"label":"Total Promoters","value":12.13},
                  {"label":"Total Public & Others","value":3.20}
                ]
        },
        "labels": {
            "outer": {
                "pieDistance": 20
            },
            "inner": {
                "hideWhenLessThanPercentage": 3
            },
            "mainLabel": {
                "fontSize": 11
            },
            "percentage": {
                "color": "#ffffff",
                "decimalPlaces": 0
            },
            "value": {
                "color": "#adadad",
                "fontSize": 11
            },
            "lines": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "truncation": {
                "enabled": true,
                "truncateLength": 20
            }
        },
        "tooltips": {
            "enabled": true,
            "type": "placeholder",
            "string": "{label}: {percentage}%"
        },
        "effects": {
            "pullOutSegmentOnClick": {
                "effect": "linear",
                "speed": 400,
                "size": 8
            }
        },
        "misc": {
            "gradient": {
                "enabled": true,
                "percentage": 100
            }
        },
        "callbacks": {}
    });
```

My problem is, the label text that I'm getting in is long. The data is going beyond the canvas boundaries. I cannot go bigger than the defined size because its a piece of website that I'm working on right now. Is there anyway that I can wrap the label text.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you replace `<?php include 'php/shpChart.php'; ?>` with the kind of output you expect it to have?

Comment: @dsummersl I've added the output :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, line wrapping is not currently supported in d3pie ([see this issue](https://github.com/benkeen/d3pie/issues/66)).

But, you could turn off truncation, and use a smaller font:

```
...
...
"mainLabel": {
    "fontSize": 9
},
...
...
"truncation": {
    "enabled": false
}
...
...
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/dsummersl/mw3660ex/

The tooltips are also cut off when using that long label. I'd suggest either changing `string` from `{label}: {percentage}%` to `{percentage}%`, or turning it off altogether.

Comment: Thank for helping me out here. I guess I'll go with the smaller font size :)